# Triangle and sparse matrixes in C++

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, sparse-matrix

This is a very simple question - what is the best practice to work with triangle matrixes and to work with sparse matrices in C++?

For triangle matrix I suggest a data format as easy as

```
double* myMatrix;
int dimension;
```

as data structure in custom class. (I suggest that it was a square matrix in the full form.) And there will be methods for setting and accessing elements.

For sparse matrices - I know a couple of methods like saving just positions of elements in the row/column and their values. It's the question for your experience - which implementation of sparse matrix will be the best one?

P.S. Less memory, less CPU usage - that is my target, I am looking for the best solution, not the simplest one. All matrices will be used for solving systems of linear equations. And the size of matrices will be huge.

Thanks a lot for every advice!

Comment: How about a 3rd party library like Eigen?

Comment: Unless you are an expert, use pre-existing libraries. I recommend Tim Davis's codes, e.g. CSparse, UMFPACK.

Comment: 3rd party library is not a solution in my situation. Maybe, I can search for open source solutions and use some parts as their lisence allows, but I can't add extern modules as dlls and libs to my project due to some reasons.

Comment: There seems to be a decent amount of existing research. Have a look there first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix

Comment: Who said anything about DLLs? I use third party code (CSparse) and just compile it into my code. Anyway, if you know absolutely nothing about sparse matrix algorithms, attempting to write effective ones starting with a Stack Overflow question is doomed to failure. At the very least buy a good book. Again, Tim Davis's book is excellent.

Comment: See the [Matrix Template Library](http://www.simunova.com/en/node/24)

Comment: How about using std::map<std::pair<int,int>,double>?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just asked if anybody done something with such algorithms by himself and can give an advice a little bit better then "google and re-use". And I wasn't hoping that the question on SO will be the miracle to solve my problems :) As far as most of people say that CSparse is the best one, I will take a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no idea about the structure of the matrix, then it is basically the same as a map.  You could use `std::map<std::pair<int,int>,double>`.  Or perhaps `std::unordered_map` if you have it.